# Every row is executed twice

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have found a bug - and I haven't found any solution to this.

I have a code in ASP.NET Core (using VSPro 2019 16.5.0):

```
public IActionResult CreateSubGroup(MyClass model, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (ModelState.CreateMyClassValidation())
            {
                if (!db.MyClass.Where(x => x.Title == model.Title).Any())
                {
                    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
                    var code = new MyClass { Title = model.Title, IdGroup = model.IdGroup, GroupCode = model.GroupCode};
                    db.MyClass.Add(code);
                    var result = db.SaveChanges();
                    if (result > 0)//if there was no issue (at least one row was changed)
                    {
                        this.AddNotification(MessagesHandler.Success, $"Item\"{model.Title}\" was successfully created.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.AddNotification(MessagesHandler.Error, $"Item \"{model.Title}\" cannot be created.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this.AddNotification(MessagesHandler.Error, $"Item \"{model.Title}\" already exists.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.AddNotification(MessagesHandler.Error, $"ErrorMessage.");
            }
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
```

Creating of new Item always crashes with unique code exception from DB - During debuging I have found, that every row is executed twice (and I don't know why??) - so also the row db.SaveChanges() is executed twice and that's why I got this exception.

Second bad thing is, that not even the first attempt to save database is not executed (= new Item is not created in DB).

Have you seen this error?

EDIT:

I have found, that it happens only when data are posted from view with JS/AJAX (from modal window)

Here is the code for sending data:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalWindow" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalForm" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <form id="ModalForm" action="" method="post" class="validator">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Id"></label>
                                <input class="form-control" asp-for="Id" value="" readonly data-val="false">
                                <div class="form-text text-muted small">ID cannot be changed!</div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Title"></label>
                                <input class="form-control mlfb-create" asp-for="Title" placeholder="Title" value="" autofocus tabindex="@(++tabindex)">
                                <span class="text-danger small" asp-validation-for="Title"></span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="IdGroup"></label>
                                <select class="selectpicker form-control" asp-for="IdGroup" data-live-search="true" data-style="btn-info" tabindex="@(++tabindex)">
                                    @if (data?.GroupData != null)
                                    {
                                        @foreach (var item in data?.GroupData)
                                        {
                                            <option value="@(item.Id)">@item.Title</option>
                                        }
                                    }
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="GroupCode"></label>
                                <input class="form-control mlfb-create" asp-for="GroupCode" placeholder="Title" value="" autofocus tabindex="@(++tabindex)">
                                <span class="text-danger small" asp-validation-for="GroupCode"></span>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center modal-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success _modal-buttton-save" tabindex="@(++tabindex)"><i class="fas fa-check mr-2"></i><span>Save</span></button>
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fas fa-times mr-2"></i>Cancel</button>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            "use strict";

            $(document).on('click', '._createSubFormButton', function () {
                $('#ModalWindow').modal('show');

                $('.modal-title').text('Creating of subgroup');

                $('.modal-buttton-save span').text('Create');

                $('#ModalForm').attr('action', '/MyCode/CreateSubGroup/?returnurl=' + window.location.href);
            });

            // Edit form
            $(document).on('click', 'tr ._editSubFormButton', function () { 
                $('#ModalWindow').modal('show');
                var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

                var Id = $tr.find('._Id').text();
                var Title = $tr.find('._Title').text();
                var IdGroup = $tr.find('._IdGroup').text();
                var GroupCode = $tr.find('._GroupCode').text();

                $('.modal-title').text('Editing of subgroup');
                $('#ModalForm').attr('action', '/MyCode/EditSubGroup/' + Id + '?returnurl=' + window.location.href);
                $('#Id').val(Id);
                $('#Title').val(Title);
                $('#GroupCode').val(GroupCode);
            });

            // form validation reset during closing modal form
            $('#ModalWindow').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
                $(this).find('form').trigger('reset');
                $('#IdGroup').load();
                $('.form-group .is-invalid').each(function () { $(this).removeClass('is-invalid'); });
                $('.form-group .is-valid').each(function () { $(this).removeClass('is-valid'); });
                $('.form-text.text-danger').each(function () { $(this).removeClass('text-danger'); });
                $('.form-text.text-success').each(function () { $(this).removeClass('text-success'); });
                $('.invalid-feedback').each(function () { $(this).remove(); });
            });
$(document).on('submit', '#ModalForm', function (e) {
            var form = $('#ModalForm');

            if (form.valid()) {

                console.log(form.serializeArray());


                $.ajax({
                    url: form.attr("action"),
                    type: form.attr("method"),
                    data: form.serializeArray()

                }).done(function () {
                    console.log('done');
                    $tr.find('._Number').text();
                    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                })
                    .fail(function () {
                        console.log('fail');
                    });

                $('#ModalWindow').modal('hide');
            }
        });
```

error I got:
[image: Error message]

Comment: Without knowing the details about the exception it is difficult to help. Please show the error message and the stacktrace for the first exception your code encounters, then do the same for the second one

Comment: Are two http requests being sent for some reason (ie. client side issue)?

Comment: I have edited my question - and posting the error I got...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging this code? Debugging with setting breakpoints and stepping through the code would help you find what is wrong with this code.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that - in debugging mode first row is executed twice, then next one twice etc. I thought, that it's only in debugging mode, but it seems to be in running and debugging mode the same...

Comment: Could you add also the code of the HTML form please (the code of the submit button)?